# Pandas dataframe add rows with NaN in one column based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

For example, there are three columns in a dataframe, `x, y, z`. `x` and `y` have 3 different values with 0.5 intervals. They are coordinates so they map with each other and there will be 3*3=9 rows with some `z` values. But the actual dataframe has only let say 7 rows. How to add two missing rows with `NaN` value in `z` column? Below are the example input and output. Thank you!

**Input:**

```
DataFrame:
     x    y   z
0  -0.5   0   5
1  -0.5 -0.5  10
2    0  -0.5  7
3    0   0.5  6
4    0    0   12
5   0.5   0   8
6   0.5  0.5  2
```

**Output:**

```
DataFrame:
     x    y   z
0  -0.5   0   5
1  -0.5 -0.5  10
2    0  -0.5  7
3    0   0.5  6
4    0    0   12
5   0.5   0   8
6   0.5  0.5  2
7  -0.5  0.5  NaN   // missing row
8   0.5 -0.5  NaN   // missing row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to add the missing rows, based on a combination of `x` and `y` :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.complete('x', 'y')

     x    y     z
0 -0.5  0.0   5.0
1 -0.5 -0.5  10.0
2 -0.5  0.5   NaN
3  0.0  0.0  12.0
4  0.0 -0.5   7.0
5  0.0  0.5   6.0
6  0.5  0.0   8.0
7  0.5 -0.5   NaN
8  0.5  0.5   2.0
```

[complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) is just an efficient helper (wrapper around pandas functions); if your data does not have duplicates that can throw off `pivot`, then use it:

```py
 df.pivot('x', 'y', 'z').stack(dropna=False).rename('z').reset_index()

     x    y     z
0 -0.5 -0.5  10.0
1 -0.5  0.0   5.0
2 -0.5  0.5   NaN
3  0.0 -0.5   7.0
4  0.0  0.0  12.0
5  0.0  0.5   6.0
6  0.5 -0.5   NaN
7  0.5  0.0   8.0
8  0.5  0.5   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

new_row = {"x": -0.5, "y": 0.5, "z": np.nan}

df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know exactly how you calculate "x" and "y" values, but I guess your question is directed towards the `NaN` value in the "z" column.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Facundo Peña. But this is just an example and I have many rows so I think this way of adding missing rows manually cannot be generalized to many rows. I need to automatically detect missing x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the product of `[-0.5,0,0.5]` with `itertools.product`

```py
import itertools

lst = pd.concat([df['x'], df['y']]).unique().tolist()
p = list(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2))
```

```
print(p)

[(-0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, 0.0), (-0.5, 0.5), (0.0, -0.5), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.5), (0.5, -0.5), (0.5, 0.0), (0.5, 0.5)]
```

Then fill the missing index:

```py
out = df.set_index(['x', 'y']).reindex(p).reset_index()
```

```
print(out)

     x    y     z
0 -0.5 -0.5  10.0
1 -0.5  0.0   5.0
2 -0.5  0.5   NaN
3  0.0 -0.5   7.0
4  0.0  0.0  12.0
5  0.0  0.5   6.0
6  0.5 -0.5   NaN
7  0.5  0.0   8.0
8  0.5  0.5   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "Default" xy DataFrame, and then outer merge to it~

```
import itertools
xy = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product([-0.5, 0, 0.5], repeat=2), columns=['x', 'y'])
df.merge(xy, 'outer')
```

Output:

```
     x    y     z
0 -0.5  0.0   5.0
1 -0.5 -0.5  10.0
2  0.0 -0.5   7.0
3  0.0  0.5   6.0
4  0.0  0.0  12.0
5  0.5  0.0   8.0
6  0.5  0.5   2.0
7 -0.5  0.5   NaN
8  0.5 -0.5   NaN
```